# How to tangle conditionally based on hostname?

Tags: org-babel, literate-programming, tangle

Why is this block tangled (bar.sh), but not the second (foo.sh)?

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle bar.sh
echo bla
#+END_SRC

bla
```

---

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle (when (eq system-name 'arch) "foo.sh")
 (princ system-name)
#+END_SRC

arch
```

According to this excellent <sup>1</sup>answer, I should be able to tangle conditionally

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14034

Comment: On my system `system-name` is a string.  Try `(equal (system-name) "arch")` for the condition.  (I am using the function `system-name` because apparently the variable is deprecated.

Comment: @FranBurstall Accepted Answer. Thank you