# Can org-babel filter code blocks?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have a general emacs.org file that I load at init time with org-babel. It's made for desktop use, and I load a bunch of IDE features, face customizations, powerline and so on. However, I also sometimes use emacs on a headless server, where such configurations don't make sense but still take time loading (especially since the server is much less powerful than my desktop). But I would still like to keep other blocks (e.g. ivy, undo-tree etc). I could just take my emacs.org and delete unnecessary blocks when putting it on my server, but now I have two different files to manage, which is a pain.

Is there a way to tell org-babel "only load these code blocks"? For example by filtering tags of headers?

Comment: See related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13805/can-org-babel-conditionally-tangle-code-blocks-based-on-system-type?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty easy to do. `:tangle` can take `no` or `yes`, a filename, but also a lisp function. For example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :tangle (make-string 5 ?x)
ls -tr
#+END_SRC
```

Recall that header arguments can be set at different levels (for example as a `+#PROPERTY` under a headline) so you can have headlines for different OS, hosts, etc. Create a function that, based on the hostname, returns either `emacs.el` or `no`. When it returns `no` that block won't be tangled.