# Org Tangle if file does not exist

Tags: org-babel, emacsclient

I've been trying to work out if it's possible to tangle a file if it's not existent on the system.  I came across [Can Org Babel conditionally tangle code blocks based on system-type?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13805/can-org-babel-conditionally-tangle-code-blocks-based-on-system-type) which gave me a starting point, however when I do the following
`#+begin_src shell :tangle (when (not (file-exists-p "~/bin/eto")) ~/bin/eto)`
I get `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` when I try to tangle the src block.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to tangle that shell block to `~/bin/eto`? Then you simply need `#+begin_src shell :tangle ~/bin/eto`, right?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @aadcg I only want it tangled when the file doesn't exist, so when I set up on a new system for the first time the src block will get tangled and no other time when I make changes to my config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dalanicolai's answer is correct but you still have a problem: the legal values of the `:tangle` header are the strings `yes`, `no` or a filename, (IOW, the argument *always* has to be a string), so your elisp snippet has to be more complicated:

```
#begin_src  shell :tangle (if (not file-exists-p "foo") "foo" "bar")
...
```

Your original snippet returns `nil` if the file exists, but `nil` is not a string. The modified snippet returns the string `foo` if `foo` does not exist, but it returns the string `bar` otherwise, so the `:tangle` header *always* gets a string argument and everybody is happy.

EDIT: The OP in a comment to the question mentions that the tangling should only happen the first time (i.e. when the file does not exist) and never again. So the header should read:

```el
#begin_src  shell :tangle (if (not file-exists-p "foo") "foo" "no")
...
```

Comment: That would make sense. Thank you both NickD & dalanicolai

Comment: If this or the other answer has answered your question, please [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one or the other to indicate to others that there is an answer. Don't leave questions orphaned if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

From the [org-documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html) we find that the filename should be passed as a string (see section FILENAME), so you should place the latter ~/bin/eto between double quotes also.