# How To Tangle Org Src Code Block Under Conditions

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm using `.org` files to keep track of my system configuration across different machines and I want certain code blocks to be tangled only if certain conditions are met.

Let's say I have something like this in my `.init.el`

```
(defvar is-desktop (equal (system-name) "desktop"))
(defvar is-laptop (equal (system-name) "laptop"))
```

How would I set a specific `src` block to be tangled only `(when is-desktop)`?

*Something like this:*

```
#+begin_src shell :tangle ~/.shells/exports.sh

export EDITOR="emacsclient"

#+end_src

#+begin_src conf :tangle (when is-desktop)"~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf")

  default-cache-ttl 172800
  max-cache-ttl 282800
  pinentry-program /home/user/.stumpwm.d/modules/util/pinentry/stumpwm-pinentry

#+end_src
```

When `org-babel-tangle` the first block will be 'tangled' but the second will not.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: According to the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14034/26163), you can just use elisp directly in the source block its header. So, adapting from that answer, you would get `:tangle (when is-desktop ~/.shells/exports.sh)`

Comment: What happens if `is-desktop` is `nil`?

Comment: Assuming that `is-desktop` is defined, then `:tangle (if is-desktop "~/.shells/exports.sh" "no")` should work: the expression *has* to return a string in all cases (in this case, either the pathname or "no").

Comment: The answer under the link mentions that if the expression returns nil, then the block does not get tangled. As the answer got 12 upvotes, I assumed it was correct. I did not test it, therefore I wrote 'according to the answer...'.

Comment: Using :tangle (when (string= (system-name) "desktop") "yes) works when t, but when nil it will fail to tangle all blocks. Is there a way to just not tangle a single block?